# jquery mouseover target each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I want to say when I hover over .project, I want p tag to appear. But the code I have written shows all of the p tag for every project at the same time. How can I say that only when i have on that project that p under that project appears. without adding extra classes?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.project').hover(
     function () {
       $('.project p').css({"visibility":"visible"});
     },
     function () {
       $('.project p').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
     }
 );

});
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `this` keyword, and to do that you need to use `find()`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.project').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('p').css({"visibility":"visible"});
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find('p').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
        }
   );
});
```

Here's another way to do it

```
$('.project').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('p', this).css('visibility', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
});
```